# Pygame multiple PS3 controllers BUTTON numbering is not consistent

Tags: python, pygame

I'm writing pygame-based code for two players / two PS3 controllers.
My problem is that the button numbering appears to be inconsistent between controllers when using two at the same time. 
(Pressing the yellow button on one controller may give me a button number of 4, but 0 for the other controller). 
Is this normal behaviour or is my code erroneous?

```
import pygame
pygame.init()    
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Get the number of joysticks attached
joystick_count = pygame.joystick.get_count()

# Check for events
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN:
            print("Joystick button pressed.")
        if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONUP:
            print("Joystick button released.")

    # For each joystick:
    for j in range(joystick_count):
        joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(j)
        joystick.init()

        buttons = joystick.get_numbuttons()
        for i in range( buttons ):
            button = joystick.get_button( i )
            if button != 0:
                print("Joystick {:1} Button {:>2} value: {}".format(j,i,button) )

    clock.tick(20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One controller was set to DirectInput (which works well with my pygame), whereas the other was set to Xinput.
When they are both set to DirectInput, button mapping is always consistent!